# Are guys with long hair frowned upon in CIS/CS positions?

Tags: professionalism, dress-code

I'm currently in college and stuck between a CIS or CS major (the answer to this question will not influence my decision, so answer honestly) but I know I definitely want to have a computer-oriented position. In a position where I'd likely get little to no customer interaction, would long hair be an issue? I have Kurt Cobain-style shoulder-length hair. I wash it at least once a day so the cleanliness part isn't a problem. I'm sure I could also work with it to make it look more professional if need be. Would this be an issue or are CIS/CS positions a little more lenient?

Comment: In any particular county / culture?

Comment: I'd choose the field that interests you most between CS and CIS. That is much more important.

Comment: Some long haired men I know tie their hair back when they want to look more formal.

Comment: if it's not unusual to the culture, then it's probably fine, especially for a non client facing position, but it's very much up to the employers perception of what is reasonable.

Comment: No good at all. In CS you want a neck-beard.

Answer (score 12):

That depends *entirely* on the industry you will be working in. CS is not a field of it's own in that regard. You will always be working for *someone* who wants more of their manual labor optimized and replaced by more computers. And that someone will decide what the company as a whole looks like.

If you employer is a bank for example, you can expect to adjust to suit and tie for everyday life, while online shops in the fashion industry are probably the other extreme. Any company will have it's own dress code, you just need to find the one that fits.

Comment: Almost entirely. Country and culture also affect this. But I absolutely agre with the last sentence -- either find a position that will take you as you are, or become more flexible about details like this one which really don't matter a lot. Same as dating; if my lady said she didn't like my moustache it would go, despite my having worn it for decades... but as it happens we mutually s elected each other partly because she doesn't object to it.

Comment: had to shave mine, then she made me grow it back... go figure

Comment: This. CS has _some_ input, in that you'll certainly find companies where "the computer guys" are less formal than people in other departments, but ultimately, it comes down to location, the industry a company is in, and the company's individual culture.